# How to bind and output data to codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables in the database, one stores a list of departments (id and name), and the other a list of doctors, and each doctor is attached to the department, while in the table of doctors, the doctor is attached to the department by department id.
My task is to display a list of doctors in a bootstrap table and so that the department field displays not the department ID but the name of the department, how can I do it?

view

```
     <!-- Table with stripped rows -->
          <table class="table datatable" id="example">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($doctors_list as $dl) : ?>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?= $i; ?></th>
                <td><?= $dl['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $dl['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$dl['department']; ?> </td>
                <td><?= $dl['phone']; ?></td>
              </tr>
               <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

controller

```
    public function doctors_list()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
    $data['doctors_list'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['role_id' => 2])->result_array();
    $data['department_list'] = $this->db->get('departments')->result_array();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]', [
        'is_unique' => 'This email has already registered!'
    ]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|matches[password2]', [
        'matches' => 'Password dont match!',
        'min_length' => 'Password too short!'
    ]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password', 'required|trim|matches[password1]');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
       $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar_admin', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/doctors_list', $data);
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
         $role_id = $this->input->post('role_id', true);
         $department = $this->input->post('department', true);
        $data = [
            'name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('name', true)),
            'email' => htmlspecialchars($email),
            'image' => 'default.jpg',
            'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password1'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'role_id' => htmlspecialchars($role_id),
            'department' => htmlspecialchars($department),
            'phone' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('phone', true)),
            'is_active' => 1,
            'date_created' => time()
        ];

        $this->db->insert('user', $data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Congratulation! your account has been created. Please activate your account </div>');
        redirect('admin/doctors_list');
    }
```

i am trying to do so

```
<?=$department_list[$dl['department']]; ?>
```

but i get an error

Answer (score 0):

After the fix

Controller

```
public function doctors_list()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
    $data['doctors_list'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['role_id' => 2])->result_array();
   
    $departments = $this->db->get('departments')->result_array();
    $data['department_list'] = array_combine(array_column($departments, 'id'),array_column($departments, 'dep_name') );


     
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]', [
        'is_unique' => 'This email has already registered!'
    ]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|matches[password2]', [
        'matches' => 'Password dont match!',
        'min_length' => 'Password too short!'
    ]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password', 'required|trim|matches[password1]');
  

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
       $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar_admin', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/doctors_list', $data);
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else  {
        $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
         $role_id = $this->input->post('role_id', true);
         $department = $this->input->post('department', true);
        $data = [
            'name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('name', true)),
            'email' => htmlspecialchars($email),
            'image' => 'default.jpg',
            'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password1'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'role_id' => htmlspecialchars($role_id),
            'department' => htmlspecialchars($department),
            'phone' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('phone', true)),
            'is_active' => 1,
            'date_created' => time()
        ];

        $this->db->insert('user', $data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Congratulation! your account has been created. Please activate your account </div>');
        redirect('admin/doctors_list');
    }
```

}
And View

```
   <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?= $i; ?></th>
                <td><?= $dl['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $dl['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $department_list[$dl['department']]; ?> </td>
                <td><?= $dl['phone']; ?></td>
                <td>
                
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editmodal<?= $dl['id']; ?>"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
                
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#delmodal<?=$dl['id']?>">
         <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
          </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

View of the site before fixing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnwyT.jpg)

and after fix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7TMX.jpg)

Comment: I don't see any errors in this code. Is it showing errors/missing files in the developer tools (F12) "console" tab? Or if you right mouse click on what should be the "delete" button, and choose "inspect element", does it show any php errors in the html?

Comment: Thanks, I chose the second option, it works. As for the error, when choosing the first option, if you look at the html code, then all styles and connected plugins are missing there, only the table code remains, I don’t know where the conflict occurs. I have php version 8.0, maybe from this?

Comment: Very odd, it looks like it's not rendering the header, menu and footer views at all, even though they are being loaded in the controller. It might be a php 8 (+/- codeigniter 3) thing, but unfortunately I can't test it any further with my current set up (php 7.4). Glad the second option does work though!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).